# Lamport's logical clock implementation

Tags: java

I'm working on a `Lamport's logical clock` for my *college assignment* and have to either **implement** or **simulate** it.

I'd `Google` a lot and searched [here](http://stackoverflow.com) too but not getting any good result. Will anybody help me out in implementing this?
At least can provide some link or resource helpful to me which `java` classes of `Java-API` will be helpful or to be used for the implementation.

Comment: For what are you searching exactly? The algorithm is pretty simple: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamps).

Comment: @Sirko: I'd to write the program for my lab assignment ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most useful resource is going to be your own mind.  Re-read the paper.  What is the essential condition under which a Lamport clock is correct?  (Hint -- you can guarantee one event happened *after* another.)

Have a look at [this presentation](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~yairamir/cs437/week13/sld017.htm).  [This tutorial](http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra1/wskrap/publichtml/200210804.pdf) is also helpful.

Then try to write out a description of the algorithm and how it works.  Draw pictures.